# VS Code @typedef capitalization

Tags: visual-studio-code, jsdoc

I noticed today while working on a very small JS file that my defined type wasn't allowing intellisense when a variable was declared later on as being of that type.  Turns out that changing the typedef to have a capital letter fixes the issue.  My type definition is at the top of the file and the variable that is of that type is within an IIFE.

If I move the type definition inside the IIFE, then it works no matter the case of the type's name.  However, leaving the type definition at the top of the file (outside the IIFE) and making the name capitalized also makes it work.

Is it documented anywhere that a capitalized type definition makes it global?

EDIT: Adding a couple screenshots. This seems to be sporadic to reproduce using simple examples.

[Non-working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HbJn0.png)
[Working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MAbVW.png)

**EDIT_2:** It seems to be related to having a variable with the exact same name as the type definition.

```js
/**
 * An object that stores all the necessary contextual data
 * Defined inside the HTML file loaded for the alert
 * @typedef {Object} Test
 * @prop {Number} personId person_id of the patient
 */

(function() {
    /** @type {Test} */
    const Test = window.Test;
    Test
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should consider the `@typedef` as being a variable – one that's only usable in your type declarations.

That means that you can override that variable in your local scope, so that it means something else there.

And that's exactly what you are doing here.

Comment: Thanks for your response!  Would you be able to provide a modified example of mine to show how I should be using it?